# Where is the information in the node_info hook displayed in drupal

Tags: hooks

I am beginning with drupal. I cannot see where the information which I write in the hook node_info displayed in drupal. What is the link to check it?

Comment: version D7 or D6?

Answer (score 0):

You should see it on the add content page. If you don't, either you need to clear cache, the module isn't enabled, or the module is coded incorrectly.